# Two (supposedly) identical date objects in R are not equal?

Tags: r, date

I have a simple question. I have two Date objects in R that are supposed to be identical (they have the same value and class), but R is saying they are not equal. I am running on linux though I get the same result on a windows machine. Why is this happening?

code:

```
start=as.Date("2014-12-31")
finish=as.Date("2014-11-28")
dates = seq(start,finish,length=6)
christmasEve = as.Date("2014-12-24")
print(dates[2])
print(christmasEve)
print(class(dates[2]))
print(class(christmasEve))
(christmasEve==dates[2])
```

output:

```
[1] "2014-12-24"
[1] "2014-12-24"
[1] "Date"
[1] "Date"
[1] FALSE
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

-Paul

Comment: woops, thank you for pointing out. sample rate is 6.

Comment: `unclass(christmasEve); unclass(dates[2])`

Comment: Try `dput(dates[2])` and `dput(christmasEve)` and `all.equal(christmasEve,dates[2])`. It was probably caused because `(finish - start)/6` = `-5.5`

Comment: @ Roland -- thank you! now I see what is happening and should be able to fix it

Comment: @ michael, I don't see why this would be a problem. dates[2] is outputting the correct date

Comment: it seems to me that the print function for dates should be more informative... I would think that for any simple object, printing the value and class should be enough to determine if they are equal, no?

Comment: Thanks for all of the help. I solved the problem by replacing `dates = seq(start,finish,length=6)` with `dates = as.Date(floor(as.numeric(seq(newMonthEnds[i],newMonthEnds[i+1],length=6))))`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are dividing a number of days that is not a multiple of six by six.  Check out:

```
as.numeric(dates)
# [1] 16435.0 16428.4 16421.8 16415.2 16408.6 16402.0

start - finish
# Time difference of 33 days
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are creating the dates as a sequence the dates are not exact round numbers.

```
> as.numeric(dates)
[1] 16435.0 16428.4 16421.8 16415.2 16408.6 16402.0
> as.numeric(christmasEve)
[1] 16428
> as.character(christmasEve) == as.character(dates[2])
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to test your code as there is no `sampleRate`. I assumed that `sampleRate` is 6. You could compare your dates with the code below:

```
all(as.character(christmasEve) == as.character(dates[2]))
```

The whole things should work like that

```
> sampleRate <- 6
> 
> start=as.Date("2014-12-31")
> finish=as.Date("2014-11-28")
> dates = seq(start,finish,length=sampleRate)
> christmasEve = as.Date("2014-12-24")
> print(dates[2])
[1] "2014-12-24"
> print(christmasEve)
[1] "2014-12-24"
> print(class(dates[2]))
[1] "Date"
> print(class(christmasEve))
[1] "Date"
> (christmasEve==dates[2])
[1] FALSE
> 
> all(christmasEve == dates[2])
[1] FALSE
> all(as.character(christmasEve) == as.character(dates[2])
+ )
[1] TRUE
```